# Magento 2 error Primary db_schema doesn't exists

Tags: magento2, db-schema

I am getting this error on Magento 2.3.6 when running

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade


Updating modules:
Schema creation/updates:
Primary db_schema file doesn`t exists
```

Any idea what may cause this issue ?

Comment: have you installed Magento ?
`php bin/magento setup:install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file db_schema.xml should be present in app/etc

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."